# How y can get the "profile_pic_id" with python

Tags: python, json, instagram

I want to get the "profile_pic_id" from the json list

I can get the 'follower_count' , 'following_count' and the 'username'

```py
import requests
import json
import  re

pk = input("")

def getEndpoint(idUser):
    info=[]
    idUser=idUser.replace('\"','')
    endPoint='https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/idUser/info/'
    res=requests.get(endPoint.replace('idUser',idUser))
    try:
        full_name=json.dumps(res.json()['user']['full_name']['profile_pic_url'])
        try:
            fullName=re.sub('[^a-zA-Z \n]', ' ',full_name).lower().replace(',', ' ').replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', ' ')
            fullName=" ".join(fullName.split())
            info.append(fullName)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            info.append('')
        followersCount=json.dumps(res.json()['user']['follower_count'])
        followingCount=json.dumps(res.json()['user']['following_count'])
        followingCount=json.dumps(res.json()['user']['profile_pic_url'])
        username=json.dumps(res.json()['user']['username']).replace('\"','')
        info.append(username)
        info.append(followersCount)
        info.append(followingCount)
        info.append(profile_pic_url)
        return info
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return None

print(getEndpoint(pk))
```

I expect the output is followers, following and profile_pic_url, but the actual is follower and following only

Answer (score 0):

```
'''
import requests
import json
import  re
#'https://www.instagram.com/web/search/topsearch/?query={query}' para averiguar el pk 
print("Colocar tu PK:")
pk = input("")

def getEndpoint(idUser):
    info=[]
    idUser=idUser.replace('\"','')
    endPoint='https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/idUser/info/'
    res=requests.get(endPoint.replace('idUser',idUser))
    try:
        full_name=json.dumps(res.json()['user']['full_name'])
        try:
            fullName=re.sub('[^a-zA-Z \n]', ' ',full_name).lower().replace(',', ' ').replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', ' ')
            fullName=" ".join(fullName.split())
            info.append(fullName)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            info.append('')
        followersCount=json.dumps(res.json()['user']['follower_count'])
        followingCount=json.dumps(res.json()['user']['following_count'])
        profile_pic_url=json.dumps(res.json()['user']['profile_pic_url'])
        username=json.dumps(res.json()['user']['username']).replace('\"','')
        info.append(username)
        info.append(followersCount)
        info.append(followingCount)
        info.append(profile_pic_url) 
        return info
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return None

print(getEndpoint(pk))
'''
```